# Linux-Check Linux process history

Tags: linux

Is there any way to check Linux process history?

There's a program here but the link is no longer available.

[Process Accounting](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/)

Comment: You're going to have to be a little more specific as to what you mean by that. What do you want checked, etc...?

Comment: Thanks @JesusRamos. It was my fault. I need to check history log about process or program in Linux system.  Someone offered me the link above but it's not available now.  So I asked if there's any other resource?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get a history of the executed processes. Take a look at the program GNU acct: http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/